# How to correctly open UTF-8 files in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a question. This code open fine the txt files with english text, but when I trying to open the txt files with cyrillic text... the cyrillic symbols are "squares". Is it possible to resolve this problem?

```
        string fileData = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileData);
        richTextBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();

        SavedFile = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        dataTextBox.SaveFile(SavedFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Solution:

```
        string fileData = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileData, Encoding.Default);
        richTextBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
```

Comment: You right! The coding of my document was ANSI. But then why Windows notepad can see the symbols, but RichTextBox - not?

Comment: Notepad detects the encoding heuristically, it doesn't always assume all files are UTF8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And you are SURE the file is UTF8, right? If you write string `str = sr.ReadToEnd();`, place a breakpoint on the next line and watch `str` in Visual Studio, you see cyrillic text right? Try opening the file in notepad, File->Save As and select UTF8 as encoding.

The reason notepad is able to "read" the file is that it uses the user codepage, and in  your case it's probably the Windows-1251 (Cyrillic) Codepage. `StreamReader` tries to read the file as UTF8. If you want you can force `StreamReader` to use a different codepage. The second parameter is the `Encoding` you want to use. You pass `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)` for cyrillic. Sadly you must know the `Encoding` "a priori" (=before) reading the file.

Comment: The text was in ANSI. When I converting it into the UTF8 in Notepad, it  starts open fine.

Comment: Notepad doesn't show the codepage. For ANSI he means "the local one byte one symbol codepage". If you go here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page#Windows_.28ANSI.29_code_pages you'll see that there isn't a single ANSI codepage.

Comment: But, why I can not to save the file in UTF8?

Comment: My files always saved as ANSI.                 SavedFile = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                dataTextBox.SaveFile(SavedFile, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

Comment: @user922907 there is at least an open bug for `RichTextBox` that it doesn't load correctly UTF8 files http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/435669/richtextbox-control-does-not-support-utf-8 probably it's the same for the Save operation.

Comment: @user922907 you can try to save the file with RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText this should save the file in UNICODE. The file size will nearly double. StreamReader can autodetect UNICODE files.

Comment: It saves, but the I cannot to open it again. After "save" only  the "squares" and different symbols showing up. But ok... I will try to do anything to fix it myself. Thank You!

Comment: @user922907 Then you have to tell to the StreamReader the encoding of UTF16. `Encoding.Unicode`

Comment: Encoding.Default  -  solution of my problem. (Added on the top)

Answer (score 1):

StreamWriter, by default read by UTF-8 encoding format unless explicitly specified.

Try converting the text to Windows Encoding and try reading it again with same code.

Comment: Ok! The RichTextBox opening UTF8 good. My text was in ANSI. Is it possible to open the ANSI files too without any problems?